# How can I drag view without any change?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have a textview.when on touch this view, I am starting drag operations.But textview styles are changing after drag event started.(such as; width: "fill_parent" to "wrap_content" and lighter background color etc.).How can I disable/prevent to this animation? How can I drag `without` any change?

***onTouch*** (I am starting drag)

```
   DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
   view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
   view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```